# Access violation in Lazarus

Tags: pointers, freepascal, lazarus

I've been doing my university project and I've stumbled upon problem I cannot solve.
After declaring variable (a pointer to TButton) I cannot use it. I'll copy a part of my code to help show the problem.

So before the implementation I have

```
private
    prevButton : ^TButton;
```

After that I use OnClick procedure with my buttons

```
procedure TForm2.MissingButtonClick(Sender : TObject);
var
    b : TButton;
begin
     b := Sender as TButton;
     prevButton := @b;
     showmessage(prevButton^.Caption);
end;
```

And caption is shown no problem. But then when I use my OnClick procedure and try to change labels caption I get access violation.

```
procedure TForm2.LabelClick(Sender : TObject);
var
    l : TLabel;
begin
     l := Sender as TLabel;
     if prevButton = nil then
        showmessage('nil');
     if prevButton <> nil then begin
        showmessage(prevButton^.Caption);
        l.Caption := (prevButton^.Caption);
        prevButton^.OnClick := @AlreadyClicked;
        prevButton^.Free;
        prevButton^ := nil;
        prevButton := nil;
        refreshLabels(words);
     end;
end;
```

So here is the question, why can't I use my variable in this procedure if I could use it without problem second earlier in other procedure.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is severely flawed in several places.

First, the initial declaration is incorrect. A variable of type TButton is already a pointer, so you don't have to dereference it:

```
private
  prevButton: TButton;
```

You also don't have to dereference it when assigning to it or using it:

```
procedure TForm2.MissingButtonClick(Sender : TObject);
begin
  prevButton := TButton(Sender);
  showmessage(prevButton.Caption);
end;
```

I'm not sure what your `LabelClick` event is trying to accomplish. If you free `prevButton`, you also invalidate the original button to which you pointed it. In other words, if you assigned `prevButton := Button1;`, and then `prevButton.Free;`, you've also freed `Button1`, and I don't think that's your intent. You can safely assign `nil` to `prevButton`, but don't free it also:

```
prevButton := nil;   // No longer points to existing object instance
```

If you want to change the OnClick of an existing button, don't jump through all of those hoops:

```
// Assign this to the button's OnClick in the Object Inspector
procedure TForm1.Button1FirstClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('First time I was clicked');
  Button1.OnClick := @Button1AfterClicked;
end;

// Create these two in the code editor, and declare it in the 
// form declaration, but don't assign it to an event of the button
// in the Object Inspector
procedure TForm1.Button1AfterClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Second time clicked');
  Button1.OnClick := @Button1MoreClicks;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1MoreClicks(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Third and later clicks');
end;
```